# VBA confusion why this value being returned on stored procedure execution?

Tags: vba, stored-procedures

```
Private Sub CmdValid_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrValid:
Dim LngExec As Long
Dim varCie

Dim ret As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim StrSql
Dim DblBalance
    If Me.SF.Form.Dirty Then
        Me.SF.Form.Refresh
    End If
    DblBalance = aaRound(aaRound(Me.SF.Form.TxtCreditTotal.Value, 2) - aaRound(Me.SF.Form.TxtDebitTotal.Value, 2), 2)


    If DblBalance <> 0 Then

        MsgBox "Credit must be equal to credit. Press Delete if you want to delete this journal entry, or enter the appropriate values", vbCritical, "Validation refused"
    Else
    '---- We have to create the two record into the General ledger detail

        StrSql = "EXEC SpValidGenLedDet " & str(Me.GLHCode)
        LngExec = aaExecuteSP(StrSql)
        If LngExec = 0 Then
            DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
            StrSql = "EXEC SpDelGenLedDetTmp " & str(Me.GLHCode)
            LngExec = aaExecuteSP(StrSql)
            DoCmd.SetWarnings (True)
            ret = MsgBox("This entry is successfully validated. Do you want to create another entry ?" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "click YES to add a new one , NO to close this form", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "validation accepted")
            If ret = vbYes Then
                varCie = Me.CboGlHInternalCie
                DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
                If Not IsNull(varCie) Then
                    Me.GlHInternalCie = CLng(varCie)
                End If
            Else
                DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "There was an error while Writing the accounting lines into the General ledger, retry to validate or press delete to cancel the transaction"
        End If
    End If
finValid:
    Exit Sub
ErrValid:
    MsgBox "Error during validation", vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume finValid

End Sub
```

I have a VBA code that i need to convert to c# as given above however i am not able to get why certain things are being done or happening

For instance the above code is under `Private Sub CmdValid_Click()` and in the properties of this button click the **forecolor is set to a value of -2147483630** . When i execute the the code and check with breakpoints i get the value **-2147483630 in LngExec**.

However the procedure SpDelGenLedDetTmp is just a simple delete procedure with a where clause

```
    **

    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SpDelGenLedTmp]    Script Date: 10/28/2012 12:27:47 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
    GO
    ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpDelGenLedTmp]
        (@GHDHeader_1   [int])
    AS DELETE [ABOUSQL].[dbo].[TblGenLedDetTmp] 
    WHERE 
        ( [GHDHeader]    = @GHDHeader_1)

**
```

---

```
Function aaExecuteSP(StrSql) As Long
On Error GoTo ErrGetData
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim isok
Set cnn = aaDbConnect()

cnn.Execute (StrSql)

aaExecuteSP = 0
FinGetData:
    Exit Function
ErrGetData:
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    aaExecuteSP = Err.Number
End If
    Resume FinGetData



End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated i am very new to VBA

Thanks and regards

Comment: Since you never show what `aaExecuteSP` looks like, it's impossible to tell why its return value is what it is.

Comment: Read [KB185125: How To Invoke a Stored Procedure with ADO Query Using VBA/C++/Java](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185125/en-us). Mainly the `' Open recordset.` part in the code sample.

Comment: -2147483630 is hex 80000012, which is the code for the system `Button Text` color. That makes sense for the button forecolor, but unless it's also a common ADODB error code I don't see why it would be the result of `aaExecuteSP`. Maybe show the rest of `CmdValid_Click`?

Comment: check my edit have given the whole code now

Comment: Is spValidGenLedDet being called and returning 0, this is slightly confusing as the question states why is this returning after executing, but below you said they are not executing?

Comment: ya its getting executed and returning 0

Comment: Updated answer, stored procedure name in sql query is not the same as the snippet sent across

Comment: Is there any C# here? Any VB6? Or is this just a VBA question with tag-whoring?

Answer (score 0):

As joe pointed out the return value being seen is an error number, so updating answer to reflect this and not just a random negative integer.

If that value is nit being used directly to change anything, it might be safe just to convert it to c# how best you see fit.,  haven't used VBA in a long tume, but it is full of funny things

**UPDATE**
The stored procedue names for the delete are not the same.  the one in the code is diferent from the stored procecure snippet you provided.

Comment: The weirdest part is this delete procedure isnt getting executed :O

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see if it is possibly failing, like putting a break point on the function that wraps the stored procedure call

Comment: i am referring to the second procedure not the first StrSql = "EXEC SpDelGenLedDetTmp " & str(Me.GLHCode)
            LngExec = aaExecuteSP(StrSql)

Comment: i know, the code is trying to execute SpDelGenLedDetTmp but the procedure you referenced is called SpDelGenLedTmp is that nothing to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line `cnn.Execute` in function `aaExecuteSP` is raising an error -2147483630.  The error handler in `aaExecuteSP` returns this error code to the caller, but discards a lot of other useful information which will help you to debug this:

```
Err.Message 
cnn.Errors collection
```

I suggest you step through with the debugger, break at the line following "ErrGetData:" in `aaExecuteSP`, and examine these properties.

BTW I think it's just a coincidence that the error code happens to be the same as the button's ForeColor property (which is [vbButtonText = &H80000012 = -2147483630](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265064(v=vs.60).aspx))

Comment: ErrGetData:
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    aaExecuteSP = Err.Number
End If
    Resume FinGetData

Comment: yup u are right its coming to the error part and not executing